# How to calculate video game math to find overal increase of income?

Tags: probability

The game is called "Blacksmith: Ancient Weapons - Merge Idle RPG", it's an android phone game.

So in this game, you have slots that you can fill with equipment. Equipment in a slot will give you income per game tick, the amount of income depends on the level of the equipment.

You can also add runes to a slot that will give additional effects. One of the runes called PROFIT rune would give fix percentage increase of income, like 50% more income from this slot.

The one that I tried to calculate is called the FORTUNE rune. It gives a chance for the equipment inside the slot to double its income for each tick. The best one would give 25% chance to double the income.

So at first, I thought that:

> it's a 25% chance to double the income for each tick, so it's the
> same as 25% increase in income

But I was wrong, it's not a chance to double the equipment income, it's a chance to double the previous tick income. So if the rune triggers three times in a row it would be:

$2inc + 4inc + 8inc$

How would I calculate the overall increase in income for this rune?

Comment: What happens if the rune is not activated? Does the the income reset to the base (let's say 1) or does it just stay the same?

Comment: Does the rune work on every tick? For example, if the rune does not double my previous income on this tick will I get the same probability $p$ to double the previous income on each tick?

Comment: If the rune doesn't activate, it will give the normal income (1inc). When it is activated, it will double the last income. So a non-activation will reset it.